# changing data type in rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an rdd

```
rdd=sc.parallelize([[True,False,False], [True,True,True], [False,False,True]])
```

I want to change the rows to integers. If I only had three elements in each row I could use

```
def asInt(x):
    return [int(x[0]), int(x[1]), int(x[2])]


rdd=rdd.map(asInt)
```

which gives me

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
```

but I have millions of rows, so I need a different solution. I would also accept any solution that uses a DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is anything particularly wrong with your approach other than manual enumeration. You could replace it with a simple list comprehension:

```
rdd.map(lambda xs: [int(x) for x in xs])
```

You can also use an `array` instead of list:

```
import array

rdd.map(lambda xs: array.array('B', xs))
```

Regarding `DataFrames`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = rdd.toDF()
df.select(*[col(c).cast("integer") for c in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the scala answer

```scala
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize( Array( Array( true, false, true ), Array( true, false, false ), Array( false, false, true ) ) )
val res = rdd.map { item => item.map { x => if ( x ) 1 else 0 } }
```